# My vertices are uneven - how do I auto-correct this?

Tags: mesh, vertices, sculpting

So I've recently started my first character model, and all was going very well with the tutorial I was following - until I noticed that the vertices on my model's head weren't even
[image]

I initially tried manually aligning them all, but it takes a very long time to do so...surely there is an easier way to align all the vertices?

Comment: Hello, what part are you talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by 'even' ? Do you mean you want your model to be symmetrical?

Comment: Yes, I want the model to be symmetrical - specifically, the head. As I've mentioned, the vertices on the right side of the head are a little uneven compared to the left, which means when I'm adding details such as eyes and the nose and mouth they're not aligned well with the face (as in they aren't following the X line as well as they should be).

Comment: Generally when you model a symmetrical object, use a Mirror modifier, in your case you'll need to remove half of your mesh. You can also select all in Edit mode and go into the Mesh panel > Symmetrize and choose the axis in the Operator Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Bisect the object (<kbd>F3</kbd>, search: bisect) and cut it down the middle, then apply a mirror modifier (side panel: somewhere below object properties, blue icon) and configure it to your desire.